# Building own Graph in Python with Dictionary

Tags: python, graph-theory

i tried to build own graph in python. Dictionaries are perfect for this but i think iam to stupid to use them.

```
def add_edge(gra, edge):

        edge = set(edge)
        vertex1 = edge.pop()
        if edge:

            vertex2 = edge.pop()
        else:

            vertex2 = vertex1
        if vertex1 in gra:
            gra[vertex1].append(vertex2)
        else:
            gra[vertex1] = [vertex2]
```

i tried this to add some edges to the graph.
When i use this:

```
z = {0:[],1:[],2:[],3:[],4:[],5:[]}

for i in range(0,6):
    add_edge(z,(i,50))
print(z)
```

i would except that it would add:

```
{0:[50],1:[50],2:[50],3:[50],4:[50],5:[50]}
```

but i get:

```
{0: [50], 1: [50], 2: [50], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [], 50: [3, 4, 5]}
```

what is wrong with my idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "older" Python implementations, a `set` is an unordered datastructure (well from [python-3.7](/questions/tagged/python-3.7) it uses insertion order).

This means that if you add an element to a set, by `.pop()` you can retrieve the elements in any order. So here you insert for example `(1, 50)`, but you retrieve it back as `50` and `1`.

But you do not need a set anyway, you can just "unpack" your tuple:

```
def add_edge(gra, edge):
    vertex1, vertex2 = edge
    if vertex1 in gra:
        gra[vertex1].append(vertex2)
    else:
        gra[vertex1] = [vertex2]
```

or in case your tuple can contain more elements, we can use for example `islice(..)` here:

```
from itertools import islice

def add_edge(gra, edge):
    vertex1, vertex2 = islice(edge, 2)
    if vertex1 in gra:
        gra[vertex1].append(vertex2)
    else:
        gra[vertex1] = [vertex2]
```

By iterating, we can also take all sorts of collections (that are not per se subscriptable).